# passing html element using to_html in flask

Tags: python, flask

I have a dataframe that contains a column containing `<canvas> something </canvas>` element. In a `flask` application, I passed this data to a template using `df.to_html()`, but it never is working and always shows the `<canvas>` within displayed html table.

[image: I intend to let the canvas element be captured by a <code>chartjs</code> function]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To enable showing the characters `<, >, and &` signs in `to_html()` method, we need to change the `escape` attribute to `False`. Because by default `to_html` method converts the characters `<, >, and &` to HTML-safe sequences. Also we need to use `safe` filter in the template file to show the tags inside the table.

As you have already found how to show the HTML properly in Flask template, I am giving an example of the operation for future readers.

`app.py` contains a dataframe with `html` tags which we want to render in the template:

```
import pandas as pd
from flask import Flask, render_template

def get_panda_data():
    tags = ["<h1>Example header</h1>",
            '<div style="color: red;">Example div</div>',
            '<input type="text" name="example_form" \
placeholder="Example input form">'
        ]
    pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', -1)
    tags_frame = pd.DataFrame(tags, columns = ["Tag Example"])
    tags_html = tags_frame.to_html(escape=False)
    return tags_html    

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    html_data = get_panda_data()
    return render_template("dataframe_example.html", html_data = html_data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = True)
```

Then in template file which is `dataframe_example.html` we can easily show the data table generated by pandas `to_html` method:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Dataframe Flask Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Dataframe Flask Example</h1>
        {{ html_data | safe }}
</body>
</html>
```

The output looks like:

[image: dataframe_template_html]

Answer (score 0):

I realized that I had to utilize the option `to_html(escape=False)` to solve this problem