# Links Within DataFrame (Flask)

Tags: python, html, pandas, dataframe, flask

I'm currently trying to create buttons within one of the columns on my DataFrame and then using .to_html to print it as a DataTable within a web page. I've managed to make the buttons clickable by using escape=False in the to_html function but I cannot get the links to go to the right place.

Below is my current attempt, I'm pretty sure it's something to do with the quotation marks.

```
def add_url(data):
    data['second name'] = "<a href='{{ url_for('player', player_id=1) }}'>Click This Button Here</a>"
```

It feels like I've tried 6 million combinations of quotation marks but when I look at the html that's generated it always seems to have random quotation marks and not where I want them to be, as shown below.

[HTML Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRDd0.png)

Here is my function that it should hook up to, it works perfectly if I put the code directly into the .html file, I just can't get it to work from the .py file within the DataFrame.

```
@app.route('/player/<int:player_id>')
def player(player_id):
    data = load_df('Data/players_pickle/'+str(player_id)+'.pickle')
    return render_template('player.html', data=data.to_html(escape=False))
```

It should eventually look like this [DataTable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1I0ZQ.png)

Any help would be much appreciated as I've been struggling with this for far too long, feels like I'm trying the same combinations over and over again!

Update:

I've continued trying different combinations of quotations but it must have something to do with encoding when it goes from the .py to the html.

All I get in the address bar when I click the link is

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/%7B%7B%20url_for('player',%20player_id=1)%20%7D%7D
```

It's obviously replacing spaces, curly braces etc with unicode and no matter what I try it keeps doing it. Could it be because it's within a Dataframe and it's just no possible when using to_html() for it to be as it should be?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
data['second name'] = '''<a href="{{ url_for('player', player_id=1) }}">Click This Button Here</a>'''
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me although it does look right within the html, I get this https://imgur.com/a5kapBd I wonder if it's a collision between escape=False and the html code? If I remove escape=False I just get the html code in the cell rather than a clickable link.

Comment: @ChappyHova In the question, there was definitely something weird going on with the "<a href='{{ url_for('player', player_id=1) }}'>Click This Button Here</a>". I see single-quotes around "player" in addition to around the href url, which are probably causing the unintended behavior?

Comment: That was just my latest attempt lol. I'd tried about 20 different combinations of quotations in different places, even with your code which looks right to me I end up with this in the address bar "%7B%7B%20url_for('player',%20player_id=1)%20%7D%7D". Seems like it's substituting characters out for URL encoding.

Comment: @ChappyHova does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47280939/5496345) help?